# Angular google maps windows not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

Other than the Polling, I cannot get the windows to show when I'm adding points manually to the map. Only if the array of markers is pre-populated, will it work. If the array has, say, 1 marker pre-populated, and then I manually add a second marker after the map loads, the first marker will show the window, but the second one won't. It's the same marker with different lat/lng. As far as I can tell, I have my code nearly identical to this plunker with the exeption being I'm not polling for data.

http://plnkr.co/edit/nbX0BIxNhxFrpzpruRWb?p=preview

```
http://54.210.49.244:4000/gMaps
```

Personal site I'm using for luls. Yes, I'm too lazy to get a real domain. It's free, ok XD 
Demonstrates the issue. Does not support IE 9 or less.

This is the controller logic.

```
.controller("gMapsController", ["$scope", '$location', function($scope, $location){
    $scope.welcomeMessage = "Welcome to Google Maps Playground"

    $scope.map = {
        center: {
            latitude: 44.41748017333282,
            longitude: 26.106005249023376
        },
        zoom: 12
    }
    $scope.id = 0;
    $scope.map.bounds = {};
    $scope.map.randomMarkers = [{
        id: 0,
        latitude: 44.42138408826953,
        longitude: 26.25385948707207,
        showWindow: false,
        title: "m9"
    },
        {
        id: 1,
        latitude: 44.39138408826953,
        longitude: 26.21385948707207,
        showWindow: false,
        title: "m9"
    }];

    $scope.id++;
    $scope.id++;
    $scope.id++;

    angular.forEach($scope.map.randomMarkers, function(marker) {
        marker.showWindow = false;

        marker.onClick = function() {
            console.log('on click - opening window');
            marker.showWindow = true;
            $scope.$apply();
        }

        marker.closeClick = function() {
            console.log('close click - hiding window');
            marker.showWindow = false;
            $scope.$apply();
        }

        console.log(marker);

    });


    var generateMarkers = function(markers) {


        markers.showWindow = false;

        markers.onClick = function() {
                console.log('on click - opening window');
                markers.showWindow = true;
                $scope.$apply();
            };

        markers.closeClick = function() {
                console.log('close click - hiding window');
                marker.showWindow = false;
                $scope.$apply();
            };

            console.log(markers);


        $scope.map.randomMarkers.push(markers);

    };

    $scope.generateMarker = function(){
        var marker = {
            id: $scope.id,
            latitude: 44.41138408826953,
            longitude: 26.23385948707207,
            showWindow: false,
            title: "m9",
            draggable: true
        };
        console.log("marker added");
        generateMarkers(marker);
        $scope.id++;
    };
```

The view

```
div.container
    button(type = "button", ng-click="generateMarker()") Add a Marker
    div.row()
        div(class = "col-md-6")
            google-map(center="map.center", zoom="map.zoom", draggable="true", bounds="map.bounds", control="map.control")
                markers(models="map.randomMarkers", coords="'self'", icon="'icon'", click="'onClick'")
                    windows(show="'showWindow'", closeClick="'closeClick'", ng-cloak)
                        div
                            | Window with additional information
```

Comment: Could this be related? https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps/issues/422

Comment: Not quite. They aren't using windows for anything. Though there could be some correlation. I'll look into it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [issues](https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps/issues?labels=&page=1&state=open) of `angular-google-maps` :

https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps/issues/354 seems related to your problem (after all your method is in the `$scope`) and [has a fix here](https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps/blob/master/example/issue-354-window-windows-rerender-content.html).